# Canvases in table, weird padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

### Intro:

I'm making a website and I want to make a `<table/>` with `<canvas/>`es in it.

**What I have done:**

I made a `<table/>` with some `<canvas/>`es in it so I can draw in them.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td><canvas></canvas></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td><canvas></canvas></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td><canvas></canvas></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    border: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
tr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
```

To make the canvases appear to look like a big box I want them to hit each other.
I made a code example: http://jsfiddle.net/Whb8u/

```js
window.onload = function(){
    if(window.addEventListener){
        var items = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            drawcanvas(items[i]);
        }
    }
};

function drawcanvas(item){
    var context = item.getContext("2d");
    var canvasWidth = item.parentNode.offsetWidth;
    var canvasHeight = item.height = item.parentNode.offsetHeight;

    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(100,100,100)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight); 
}
```

### Problem:

The canvases don't touch each other.
I already removed the table `border`, `margin`, `padding` and `spacing`.

The canvases need to have a fixed `height` of `50px`. (in the code I tried to make them hit first, which is more important than the height)

But even if I change the size in the JavaScript the `<td/>` around it is always `5px` bigger than the `<canvas/>`.

Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to fix it?

### Summary:

The grey boxes don't hit each other.
Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to fix it?
Code Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Whb8u/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per default `<canvas/>` has it's `display` property set to `inline` which means it is drawn like text. The gap you see comes from the fact that some letters like `g` draw below the baseline. One way would be changing the `display` property:

```css
canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

[See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Whb8u/1/).

Comment: Wow. So letters with "stuff in the cellar" like j, g and q is the reason for that... Interesting and peculiar in a fun way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know *why* this happens and/or how to fix it?

Its happening because the `<canvas>` element has a default vertical-align value of `baseline` .. if you don't want to change the display value you can just change the vertical-align value to bottom:

http://jsfiddle.net/Whb8u/2/